# $q notfy listener not removed after controller destroy

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller with callback for $q.notify(..) which is used by SocketService.

```
SocketService.receive().then(null, null, function (data) {
    console.log('Received data from service');
});
```

I expected that this callback will be removed when controller is destroyed. But the behaviour is different. For example if I'm in view with this controller and  I change route to different (controller is destroyed) and then back(second initiate controller) on next SocketService $q.notify this callback will be fired 2 times.

```
[Controller-1] init
[SocketService] Received event 
[Controller-1] Received data from service
[Controller-1] $on $destroy
[Controller-2] init
[Controller-2] $on $destroy
[Controller-1] init
[SocketService] Received event 
2x[Controller-1] Received data from service
```

SocketService

```
var listener = $q.defer();

receive: function () {
        return listener.promise;
},


socket.stomp.subscribe(TOPIC, function (data) {
        console.log('[SocketService] Received event ');
        listener.notify(JSON.parse(data.body));
});
```

How to remove listener callback with controller destroy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach the onProgress function to a local `defer()`  object that can be cancelled.

```
var localDefer = $q.defer();

SocketService.receive().then(null, null, function onProgress(data) {
    localDefer.notify(data);
});

//use local promise
localDefer.promise.then(null, null, function onProgress(data) {       
    console.log('Received data from service');
});
```

When the scope is destroyed, reject (or resolve) the local `defer()` object to stop local notification

```
$scope.$on("$destroy", function() {
    localDefer.reject("scope destroyed");
});
```

Once a promise is resolved (either fulfilled or rejected), further calls to the `defer()` methods (`.resolve`, `.reject`, and `.notify`) are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

That issue wasn't related with `$q` at all, its related to listener on socket. listeners didn't get remove, when controller destroy its scope. We need to do this process manually.

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function (event) {
    socket.removeAllListeners(); //will remove out all the listners
});
```

But I think, in your case you are subscribing to event, so you need to do `.unsubscribe` that event while destroying scope.

```
socket.stomp.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: It's not a DOM event listener.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but if I use the same listener in 2 diferent places it won't work anymore. I have to keep socket subcribed all the time.

Comment: @kxyz by making it specific to `socket.stomp`, will that make any changes?

Comment: There is resolve() method which stops listener but it's a not scalable solution, it will generate a lot of problems with using it in new components.

Comment: "listeners didn't get remove, when controller destroy its scope" - it's correct behaviour, the callback for listener should be removed